# Contour Integral and Residue Theory for Inverse $z$-Transform

Tags: z-transform

I'm aware that the inverse $z$-transform can be evaluated using contour integration which leads to the use of Residue Theory as a corollary and I do know of the two definitions. My question is how does one lead to the other being used? It's been many years since I studied the two.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a consequence of [Cauchy's Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), which can be used to evaluate contour integrals of analytic functions. Take a look at [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/23072/4298) for an example.